# Reshaping a Necklace to conform to a character mold

Tags: modeling

I am trying to reshape the necklace in the image to fit more around the body mold (Have sized the body mold to my real life size). So it will look more natural, rather than a straight necklace print.

So I am looking to bend the back part over the shoulders & the front part down the chest.

I am brand new to blender so have no idea what I am doing. Bought the necklace mold from someone and am trying to adjust it now. I would really appreciate any help in adjusting the necklace, or if anyone would mind doing it for me, I can send you the file no problem!

I have been trying to use a tool called "Proportional Editing" but I keep warping the necklace. So it starts bending in different directions.

Any help is highly appreicated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way: Create a plane, subdivide a bit, give it a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with the body as target (here my Suzanne), *Wrap Method > Project*, give your necklace a *Surface Deform* modifier with the plane as *Target*, click on *Bind*:

[image]

Move the plane towards the body:

[image]

The problem with this method is that of course it will deform the object on one axis only, so you may need to correct afterwards.

Another method would be to give a *Cloth* simulation to the necklace and a *Collision* to the body, play the simulation and apply the *Cloth* modifier:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like the cloth method would be the best option. You able to write me a step by step on how to do it? Like make it act as a cloth & how to make the body a collision object?

Have no idea how to do any of this XD

Comment: I've kept the default settings, in my case it worked but it may be more difficult in yours: select the necklace, go into the Physics panel, click on the Cloth button, select the body, into the Physics panel click on Collision, see what it gives, if it doesn't work fine, please share your file

Comment: Hey Moonboots, thanks for the steps. Unfortunately it didnt work for me :/ it just broke off :(

Here is the file I am using, uploaded to GDrive hope that's okay. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hb8SlAQBNkERW7NFASlnVdkBn-KntNFD/view?usp=drive_link

I just want to get the necklace to a more "natural" shape. So when I print it on a 3D Printer it will fit more comfortable. Rather than be a straight piece.

I plan to buy a heatgun to mold it more to my personal shape, so am just looking to adjust it to the current body model.

Comment: Your link asks for an authorization, I can't upload   ;)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hb8SlAQBNkERW7NFASlnVdkBn-KntNFD/view?usp=sharing

Try this link sorry!!

Comment: You need to apply the scale and rotation of your body and necklace, but also they are pretty high-poly, can't you simplify them?

Comment: I have no idea how to simplify it XD it was a file I bought from someone. So I just wanted to modify it to have a more natural looking shape. If you can;t do it, dw